# Linq to find all the elements of list1 of string present in list2 of string

Tags: c#

Removing the code as it is private one

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188166/discussion-on-question-by-user7739249-linq-to-find-all-the-elements-of-list1-of). If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] it into the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you please help here

Comment: @user7739249: No, as the question is still very, very hard to understand. It may well take you quite a lot of effort to put the question into a good state - but balance that against the help you're likely to receive if you do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "0186264-9-2019-019", "0186264-9-2019-020" };

List<string> list2 =new List<string> { "0186264-9-2019-020" };

 var d = list1.Except(list2).Any() ;
```

Comment: "if all the elements present in list2 it should return me true otherwise false", this code returns the opposite

Comment: It does so because,linq except operator is a set operator and is used to compare two sequences to find unique elements. If two list is same, it will return false otherwise true

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, `list1.Except(list2).Any()` will return true if the are elements in `list1` not in `list2` and the OP wants the opposite.

Comment: Then vice versa the list is simple, enquire list2 over list1, instead list over list2.

Comment: But that would give you the elements in list2 not in list1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) to find the difference between the 2 sets (while optimizing lookups).

```
bool allElements = !list1.Except(list2).Any();
```

`list1.Except(list2)` returns the collection of items in `list1` that are in `list2`. If it does not contain any elements, `list2` has all the items of `list1` (and maybe other items not in `list1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do using linq expression.

Here code reference.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "0186264-9-2019-019", "0186264-9-2019-020" };

List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "0186264-9-2019-020" };

List<string> Common = list1.Where(c => list2.Contains(c)).ToList();
```

As per your comment you can do using except method.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "0186264-9-2019-019", "0186264-9-2019-020" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "0186264-9-2019-020" , "0186264-9-2019-019" };


if (list1.Except(list2).Any())
{
 // All list 1 values not present in list 2
}
else
{
 // All list 1 values present in list 2      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `All` method:

```
var haveAll= list1.All(element=> list2.Contains(element))
```

Comment: You have it backwards, it should be `list2.All(element => list1.contains(element))` is what you need for "if all the elements present in list2 it should return me true otherwise false. "

Comment: This is in question "all the elements of list1"

Comment: So for each element of list1 we need to make sure it exists in list2

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi While this code will produce the desired result, its performance will decrease significantly with the number of items since lookups are full scans.

Comment: Right, in matter of performance using set makes more efficient results

Comment: Correct, which is exactly what `Except` does